# A fair die is rolled 2 times, find P(A|C)

Tags: probability, statistics

Midterm Question Help!!

A fair die is rolled 2 times. Let
A = the event that the sum of two numbers shown equals 3. 
B = the event that the sum of two numbers equals to 7.
C = the event that at least one of the numbers shown is a “1”.

The probability P(A|C) is equal to?

The probability P(B|C)is equal to?

Comment: I hope you’re not asking for answers in the middle of your exam. It sure looks that way (“Midterm Question Help!”).

Comment: @amd if it is that really sucks because I originally gave the wrong answer lol

Comment: haha no its from a practice midterm @amd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bayes Theorem, $$P(A|C)=\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}$$  $$P(B|C)=\frac{P(C|B)P(B)}{P(C)}$$

$$P(C)=1-\frac{5}{6}^2=\frac{11}{36}$$ for both

Note that the only two sequences that add to $3$ are $1,2$ and $2,1$ therefore $$P(C|A)=1$$ also using the information above $$P(A)=2\frac{1}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$$

all together $$P(A|C)=\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}=\frac{\frac{2}{36}}{\frac{11}{36}}=\frac{2}{11}$$

for 
$$P(B|C)=\frac{P(C|B)P(B)}{P(C)}$$

there are $6$ sequences that add to $7$, $(1,6),(6,1),(2,5),(5,2)(3,4),(4,3)$ therefore

$$P(C|B)=\frac{1}{3}$$ and $$P(B)=6\frac{1}{36}$$

altogether $$P(B|C)=\frac{P(C|B)P(B)}{P(C)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{11}{36}}=\frac{2}{11}$$

Comment: I get $2/11$ for both of them... this kind of things get tricky if you don't use Bayes Rule... (by that I mean that imo you just computed $\mathbb P(C)$)

Comment: Now that you mention it I think bayes rule is more appropriate. Shame on me for jumping the gun and attempting to use intuition to solve it.

Comment: @maffred yeah the right answer is 2/11

Comment: @ColinHicks Thanks!! this really helps!